# Threejs StreetView-like panorama effect

Tags: javascript, three.js

I'm trying to achieve a kind of effect between panoramas being rendered with ThreeJS on a sphere.

Actually, I'm moving the actual scene behind me using TweenMax for the timing and easing, but I would like to give it that fast-moving effect that you get on StreetView.

This is the piece of code I'm using for the transition:

```
var vector = new THREE.Vector3( 0, 0, 0);     
camera.getWorldDirection(vector);

var duration = 450;

var tweenRoomOut = new TWEEN.Tween(scene.position)
.to({
    x: -1 * vector.x * 300,
    y: -1 * vector.y * 300,
    z: -1 * vector.z * 300,        
}, duration)
.easing(TWEEN.Easing.Exponential.Out)
.onComplete( () => {
  //When finished, restart position so the scene returns to its origin
  scene.position.x = vector.x;
  scene.position.y = vector.y;
  scene.position.z = vector.z;
})
.start();
```